# translate curl PUT into ansible uri module

Tags: rest, curl, ansible

I'm trying to deploy a war file to a tomcat manager remotely with a PUT REST call.  I've been able to achieve this with curl but I would like to follow ansible best practices and use the uri module inside my playbook.

Here's the curl command that works. I'm running this from my workstation:

```
curl -k -X PUT -u $TOMCAT_USER:$TOMCAT_PW --upload-file someapp.war "https://$SERVER:8443/manager/text/deploy?path=/someapp&update=true"
```

And here's my attempt at a task to achieve the same thing (also running this on my workstation):

```
- name: Push war to Tomcat manager
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ inventory_hostname }}:8443/manager/text/deploy?path=/someapp&update=true"
    src: /opt/someapp.war
    user: "{{ tomcat_manager_username }}"
    password: "{{ tomcat_manager_password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    method: PUT
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

The ansible task passes with an OK status but it's pushing an empty file instead of the war.  I thought you could use the src parameter to replace the --upload-file flag in curl (since the uri module uses all the parameters from the file module) but apparently that's not the case.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

ansible version: 1.8.4

http://docs.ansible.com/uri_module.html

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely

Answer (score 1):

The [URI Module](http://docs.ansible.com/uri_module.html) does not take `src` as parameter.

Try using the body argument make sure the
`body="{{ lookup('file','/opt/someapp.war') }}`

Comment: It accepts all parameters for the file module but I don't think it does anything with them.  Tried using body and got `Unexpected error in during lookup: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 10: invalid start byte`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to upload a binary with the URI module.  I ended up just using the curl command with the shell module.

Comment: @KyleFrank struggling with exact same issue and I coming to the same conclusion now :(

Comment: Ansible doesn't support binary file upload at the moment